# Setting preselected values in multiple select with Ractive

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I render a `select multiple` in Ractive with a computed list of all options possible, which works great. But I could not find a proper way of preselecting values.

So far I have something like:

```
data = [{
  type: "Person",
  Name: "John",
  worksFor: [
    "1",
    "2"
]},{
   type: "department",
   id: "1",
   Name: "Sales"
},{
   type: "department",
   id: "2",
   Name: "Marketing"
},{
   type: "department",
   id: "3",
   Name: "Accounting"
}]
new Ractive({
    el: '#list',
    template: DataTpl,
    data: {myData: data},
    computed: {
        DepartmentList () {
            //some code
            return list_of_all_Departments;
        },
        PersonsList () {
            //some Code
            return list_of_persons
        });
```

So in my Template I tried

```
{{#PersonsList}}
<select multiple>
    {{#DepartmentList}}
        <option value="{{id}}" 
            {{#if _.includes(PersonsList.worksFor, id)}} selected{{/if}}>{{Name}}
        </option>
    {{/DepartmentList}}
</select>
{{/PersonsList}}
```

But this just gave me a `failed to compute`. Does anyone know how to get those preselects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things where Ractive deviates from standards. You need to put a `value` attribute on `<select>`. The selected `<option>`'s `value` becomes `<select>`'s `value`. The kind of data you'll get from `<select>` depends if it's multiple or not. If it's a single-select, you get a single value. If it's multiple-select, you'll get an array.

Setting a pre-selected value is simply the other way around. Assign a value from your data to `<select>`'s `value` and, assuming those values exist on the `<option>`s, they'll be selected. No template mangling required.

```js
Ractive.DEBUG = false;

var data = [{
  type: "Person",
  Name: "John",
  worksFor: [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}, {
  type: "department",
  id: "1",
  Name: "Sales"
}, {
  type: "department",
  id: "2",
  Name: "Marketing"
}, {
  type: "department",
  id: "3",
  Name: "Accounting"
}];

new Ractive({
  el: '#list',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    selectedDepartments: [],
    myData: data
  },
  computed: {
    DepartmentList() {
      return this.get('myData').filter(v => v.type === 'department');
    },
    PersonsList() {
      return this.get('myData').filter(v => v.type === 'Person');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive@0.8.11/ractive.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>

<script type="template/ractive" id="template">
  {{#PersonsList}}
    {{ Name }}
  
    <select multiple value="{{ worksFor }}">
      {{#DepartmentList}}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{Name}}</option>
      {{/DepartmentList}}
    </select>
  {{/PersonsList}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must give the select a value and set the value to whatever is the default value

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. As there may be multiple values (a person can work for n departments) I tried to loop through the options and write a `selected`. I just could not figure out how to determine the right values.